# Let $x$ be middle integer of three consecutive integers, what is the sum of these integers in terms of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How I reason about this.

Let $s = $ sum of consecutive integers.

$n + (n+1) + (n+2) = s$

$x = (n+1)$

So if i were to define the initial equation it would be.

$(x-1) + x + (x+1) = s$

Is this correct?

Comment: $s=3n+3=3(n+1)=3x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the sum $$(x-1)+x+(x+1)=3x$$

Comment: ***+1*** Oh Thou Plucker of the Low-Hanging Fruit! ;) Cheers!